# Archiving completed tasks to an archive file based on the current date in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

Suppose I have an `archive/` folder, which contains several .org_archive files, each for a specific month.

When I archive a task in org-mode, is there a way to make it so that the task is automatically archived to the appropriate archive file, based on the current month?

For example, if I complete a task on 07/31/2016, archiving the task should move it to `archive/archive-201607.org_archive`. The next day, on 08/01/2016, archiving another task should move it to `archive/archive-201608.org_archive`. If the appropriate file for the month doesn't exist, org-mode should create one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting `org-archive-location` as:

```el
(setq org-archive-location (concat "archive/archive-"
                                   (format-time-string "%Y%m" (current-time))
                                   ".org_archive::"))
```

Comment: This can only work if I restart Emacs at the beginning of each month.